# Add Google Map as child of a LinearLayout

Tags: android, google-maps, layout

I'm building an Android app that composes one of its screen using a selection of elements, each element being a child of a ScreenElement class that again extends `LinearLayout`.

My activity queries a database, determines the number of elements and their nature and adds each element to the Layout of the activity. The elements are regular Java classes, but as they, through their parent, extend `LinearLayout`, I can just add them doing

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.screenLayout);
for(ScreenElement e : screenElements) {
    layout.addView(e);
}
```

An element can contain all kinds of things, such as Images or text. Now, I want to have an element that can display a Map. The problem is: Google recommends to display a Map in a `Fragment`, which is not possible (because the holding class is a `View`, not an `Activity` or `Fragment`. There is also `MapView` that I could use, but all the examples I found (e.g. [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/RawMapViewDemoActivity.java) or [this](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/11/embedding-map-view-in-android.html#.V9a_Q63z_AE)) use `MapView` within an `Activity`, because `MapView` is required to connect to the overriden functions (`onPause`, `onDestroy`,...) of `Activity`.

So what I'm basically hoping to find is something that does this (not working code):

```
public class MapElement extends ScreenElement {
    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap gMap;

    public MapElement(Context con) {
        super(con);

        mapView = new MapView(con);
        gmap = new GoogleMap();

        // Set map options and features, size etc.

        mapView.setMap(gMap);
        this.addView(mapView);
    }
}
```

Well, except that this does not work. I'd be thankful for every hint you could give me!

Comment: This google maps api demo has a section "Programatically add map" which may be of use to you. https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/ProgrammaticDemoActivity.java

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but the problem is that `getSupportFragmentManager()` can only be called if the `Activity` extends `FragmentActivitiy`. This is not the case because I'm working in a non-Activity class. Your example says that a `MapFragment` cannot be created programmatically, so I can't use `MapFragment`s here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close with your not working code. You should be able to access the fragmentManager functions if you cast the context you passed in to type Activity.

```
((MainActivity)con).getSupportFragmentManager()....
```

and then you can follow the tutorial previously linked

Comment: Thanks so much. That was pretty easy. Didn't know the `supportManager` can be called from the context.